# How does one use Fusillade without ModernHttpClient in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: rest, xamarin.forms, refit

Considering that [ModernHttpClient is not required anymore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/transport-layer-security), how does one go about using Fusillade without it?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? Wondering the same thing

Comment: Looks like the current version of Fusillade can work with/without depending on your handler (NetCache.x) - [https://github.com/reactiveui/Fusillade](https://github.com/reactiveui/Fusillade)